# Transaction doesn't contain customer_id

Tags: square, square-connect

I am building a square API where I need to know customer_id for the

```
GET /v2/locations/{location_id}/transactions
```

Documentation says that it returns objects of

```
Transaction[]
```

And transaction should include `customer_id`

But my responses are not returning customer_id

- All transtactions are connected with a customer in square

EDIT: I am using PHP Rest API, and I am looking for id that is connected to the customer who made that transaction. I am bulding CRM system so I need to connect all transactions to users in the CRM (CRM has stored id of the customer)

Comment: Can you add more about your problem? what language are you using? Are you looking for `customer_id` or `client_id`? Is this for Rest APIs or on Mobile?

Comment: Hi, I am using PHP Rest API, and I am looking for id that is connected to the customer who made that transaction. I am bulding CRM system so I need to connect all transactions to users in the CRM (CRM has stored id of the customer)

Comment: How are the transactions being created?

Comment: 1. Open IOS app. 
2. select customer from menu
3. choose "new sale with cusomter"
4. choose products
5. click on charge
5. choose "credit and gift cards on file" chose credit card
6. press charge, and sign

Comment: ok then, transactions should have a `customer_id` field.

Comment: Do you have any ideas how I could debug this?

Comment: paste the raw json of your request and response into your question

Comment: Hey, I was using V1 API and it doesn't contain customer_id...
If I switch to V2 can I get "itemizations" as on V1 so I can have customer_id and products he bought?

Comment: Yes, you should use v2 to get customer info and v1 to get itemizations for point of sale transactions.